# mysql simple join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to perform a simple mysql join:

I have a tables of `matches` that features two fields which I want to join on: `team1` and `team2`.

I want to find the corresponding name of the team which is stored in the `teams` table:

```
SELECT teams.team_name AS "name1", teams.team_name AS "name2", matches.id
FROM teams, matches 
WHERE matches.id=1
AND matches.team1_id=teams.team_id
AND matches.team2_id=teams.team_id
```

If I remove either of the last and conditions I get a result, but if I include both I get an empty set?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As we do not know the data how could we comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each team you want to reference uniquely in your query you need a separate alias, otherwise SQL will compare the same row.

```
SELECT team1.team_name AS "name1", team2.team_name AS "name2", matches.id
FROM teams team1, teams team2, matches 
WHERE matches.id=1
AND matches.team1_id=team1.team_id
AND matches.team2_id=team2.team_id
```

Here we have now 2 aliases of your teams table for team1 and team2, so they can each refer to different rows.

Answer (score 2):

You need to join `teams` twice on table `matches` since two of the columns are dependent on it,

```
SELECT  a.*,                -- <<== select column that you want to project
        b.team_name AS Team1Name,
        c.Team_name AS Team2Name
FROM    matches a
        INNER JOIN teams b
            ON a.team1_ID = b.team_ID
        INNER JOIN teams c
            ON a.team2_ID = c.team_ID
-- WHERE a.id = 1
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you add `a.*`?

Comment: @Jon it just selects all columns.

Comment: to the OP, this is `ANSI SQL-92`.

Comment: Well, yes, but I just thought it needed clarification as the OP didn't mention wanting anything else from the `matches` table. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Your query as it is will only return records where the team plays against itself (which of course never happens). You want two different joins against team, so two instances of it:

```
select
    teams1.team_name as "name1"
    ,teams2.team_name as "name2"
from
    matches
join
    teams teams1 on matches.team1_id = teams1.team_id
join
    teams teams2 on matches.team2_id = teams2.team_id
where
    matches.id = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT team1.team_name AS "name1", team2.team_name AS "name2", matches.id
FROM teams as team1, teams as team2, matches 
WHERE matches.id=1
AND matches.team1_id=team1.team_id
AND matches.team2_id=team2.team_id
```